# How to add html classes to a Django template 'for-loop' dynamically?

Tags: python, css, django, django-templates

I have a CSS file where some of my styles are defined:

```css
.class-a{
    /*some styles*/
}
.class-b{
    /*some styles*/
}
.class-c{
    /*some styles*/
}
.class-d{
    /*some styles*/
}
```

These styles must be applied to the output of a django `for-loop`.

The for-loop:

```
{% for result in results %}
    <span class="[something]" > {{result}} </span> <br>
{% endfor %}
```

How do I modify this loop, the `class="[something]"` part, so that the output looks something like this, in or out of order:

```
<span class="class-a"> result </span>
<span class="class-b"> result </span>
<span class="class-c"> result </span>
```

Should I do it in the context this way:

```
results = {
    ResultOne : {
            'name' : 'someName',
            'class' : 'class-a'

    },
    ResultTwo : {
            'name' : 'someName',
            'class' : 'class-b'

    },
}
```

So that there goes something like {{result.class}} and {{ result.name}} for each {{ result }} ?

Or does there exist some other method?
What is the best way to achieve it?
Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [`cycle` template tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/builtins/#cycle):

```
{% for result in results %}
    <span class="{% cycle "class-a" "class-b" "class-c" "class-d"%}" > {{result}} </span> <br>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 5):

### Minimize logic in the Template

I think what you suggested is the way to go, i.e. pre-process your data before it goes into the template

With Django templates complex logic will become unmaintainable and unreadable quickly

### Don't mix Python and HTML

It won't be very good to have `class` as in CSS class in Python code, so maybe call it something within the domain of your models, e.g.

```
results = [
    {
            'name' : 'some_name_1',
            'result_type' : 'a'

    },
    {
            'name' : 'some_name_2',
            'result_type' : 'b'

    },
]
```

and make it so that the HTML/CSS just uses that `result-type` to resolve the CSS name, so:

```
<span class="class-{{result.result_type}}"> {{result.name}} </span>
```